# Why Java Only Allows String[] args as Main method Argument?

Tags: java, arrays, program-entry-point

Why Java only allows the main method to take argument of the form `String[] args`? i.e an array of strings

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

And why doesn't Java allow an array of int or double like

```
public static void main(int[] args)
```

or

```
public static void main(double[] args
```

And why doesn't it allow a single string or int or float rather than array of string? Something like:

```
public static void main(String args)
```

or

```
public static void main(int i)
```

Comment: because it does only allow `String[]`.

Comment: Because everything you pass as argument to your program on the command line can be represented as a string. Not as doubles or integers.

Comment: Exactly that is my question why only String[ ] and nothing else? @luk2302

Comment: Because that's what the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#sthref48) says: *The method declaration has the following form: `public static void main(String[] args)`*, which makes sense, since (as JB already said) the values passed on the command-line are actually strings. If you want something else, *you* convert as needed and handle errors as you see fit.

Comment: It's also a common convention for C

Comment: To allow `int[]` you would need to convert the numbers from the command line, you would need to decide how to do that and how to handle if it fails. Better to leave such decisions to the programmer. In your program, you can easily convert.

Comment: You may also write the main method as `public static void main(String... args)` which will allow you to call it with a single string if you are invoking it from within a running program, while still supporting command line invocation. You still need to treat it as an array (which it will be) inside the main method, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you would run a java program in a command line:

```
java YourMainClass
```

The command line arguments comes after that:

```
java YourMainClass arg1 arg2 arg3
```

This would make the `args` string array contain `"arg1"`, `"arg2"` and `"arg3"`. If you make the `args` array an `int[]`, how on earth is `arg1` going to be put into an `int`?

From the JVM's perspective, putting the command line arguments in `String`s is the safest option. Anything that the user enters, it is gotta be a bunch of `char`s.

As per the JLS,

Section 12.1.4:

> Finally, after completion of the initialization for class Test (during
>   which other consequential loading, linking, and initializing may have
>   occurred), the method main of Test is invoked.
>
> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must
>   specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is **array of
>   String**.